# How to rank by counting data in multiple rows in a column with certain conditions on it in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sql-order-by

I Have a table something like below

**edit 1** column id is the primary key

```
id  ref_id  count_value  
10     34       5
11     34       2
12     36       3
13     30       1
14     25       20
15     34       15
15     36       10
```

what I want is to align and fetch the data in such a manner where

the value in `count_value` field will be add up for each corresponding `ref_id`

so here in the example

`ref_id` 34 have three entries and total `count_value` of 22

`ref_id` 36 have two entries and total `count_value` of 13

`ref_id` 25 have one entry and total `count_value` of 20

so that I am expecting is to be in this manner

```
ref_id
 34
 25
 36
 30
```

I tried using `group by` but that isn't going to solve this I guess as I want to add up the value present inside cell and then rank it up according to the final count

regarding the condition part in the question there is a `timestamp column` and will need to get only that data which is created after certain datetime

Comment: You have no apparent PRIMARY KEY. This is likely to prove problematic further down the road

Comment: @Strawberry       column id is the PRIMARY KEY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `group by ref_id`, and then order the records by descending `sum()` of `count_value`:

```
select ref_id
from mytable
group by ref_id
order by sum(count_value) desc
```

You can add a `where` clause to the query to implement the filter on the timestamp column (which you did not show in your sample data): it goes between the `from` clause and the `group by` clause.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9509f1d76381714dd4950e173bae64be)**:

```
| ref_id |
| -----: |
|     34 |
|     25 |
|     36 |
|     30 |
```

Comment: i tried your query but that only returns the data by ranking no. of entries made by  certain user, i need it align it by  the count_value

Comment: select ref_id,count(*) from mytable WHERE DATE(timestamp) >= "2020-01-06" group by ref_id order by sum(count_value) desc

Comment: @VickySalunkhe: I don't know what you exactly mean. This produces the result that you expect for the sample data you provided (I added a fiddle to my answer for your reference).

Comment: well this works don't know why it didn't work for the first time. thank you :)